# Google maps layer onclick change style polygon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am working with layers in Google maps using geojson data.

What I have now is a layer with four different polygons and when you click on them they become from grey to green. 
But when I click again it doesn't change back to grey and that is the purpose of the click function.

```js
map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
  var color;
    if (feature.getProperty('isColorful')) {
      color = '#009900';
    }else{
      color: 'grey';
    }
    return ({
      fillColor: color,
      strokeColor: color,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });
});
```

In my case it works in my editor, https://embed.plnkr.co/hi4MtjO8f0PN6rCW70rE/ .
This is the full snippet code.

I fixed it!!
I change the position of a few lines and set it to false or true

```js
map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
var color;
if (feature.getProperty('isColorful')) {
  feature.setProperty('isColorful', false);
  color = '#009900';
}else{
  color: 'grey';
}
return /** @type {google.maps.Data.StyleOptions} */({
  fillColor: color,
  strokeColor: color,
  strokeWeight: 2
});
});

map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
var name = event.feature.getProperty('name'); 
var index = vm.areas.indexOf(name);
  if(index >= 0){
    vm.areas.splice(index,1);
    event.feature.setProperty('isColorful', false);
  } else{
    vm.areas.push(name);
    event.feature.setProperty('isColorful', true);
  }
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you show us the full relevant code? Or even better, complete the snippet with your code so we could see it working.

Comment: I will do that in a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the isColorful propertyb too in your else clause otherwise you have always false

```
map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
var color;

    if (feature.getProperty('isColorful')) {
      feature.setProperty('isColorful', false);
      color = '#009900';
    }else{
      feature.setProperty('isColorful', true);
      color: 'grey';
    }
```